# Html : view an id outside its parent id

Tags: html, loops, bootstrap-4

I have this collapse in my web app :

```
<div id="accordionExample" >
                    @foreach ($mysection as $section)
                        <?php $sec_name='home.sec'.$section->section_name ;
                        $collaps_count++;
                        $nf = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
                        $numbers_name=$nf->format($collaps_count);
                        $numbers_name=ucfirst($numbers_name);
                        $collapse_id='collapse'.$numbers_name;
                        $heading='heading'.$numbers_name;?>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="ard-header py-0 px-0" id="$heading" style="border: none">
                                    <button class=" btn w-100 text-right bg-light " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$collapse_id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{$collapse_id}}" >
                                        <h5 class="">{{__($sec_name)}}</div></h5>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div style="height:5px"></div>
                                <div id="{{$collapse_id}}" class="collapse <?php if($collaps_count == 1) echo 'show'?>"  aria-labelledby="{{$heading}}" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    @foreach ($course->Lession as $lession)
                                    @if ($section->section_name == $lession->section_name)
                                    
                                        <div class=" card-body flex-row d-flex justify-content-between">
                                            <div>- {{$lession->$less_lang}}</div>
                                                @if ($lession->id==$order->lession_id)
                                                    <div class="text-left ml-2"><i class="material-icons" style="color:green">visibility</i></div>
                                                @else
                                                    <div class="text-left ml-2"><i class="material-icons" style="color:grey">visibility</i></div>
                                                @endif
                                        </div>
                                    
                                    @endif    
                                    @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                    @endforeach;
                </div>
                <!-- End of Lessionss Card -->
            </div>
```

The problem is while looping the collapse :
first row is start inside (accordionExample) id correctly.
second row start outside (accordionExample) id.
this row start with the parent of (accordionExample) id as show in image :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors in your markup:

1. Closing div inside button tag:

`<h5 class="">{{__($sec_name)}}</div></h5>`

Replace by

`<h5 class="">{{__($sec_name)}}</h5>` OR `<h5 class=""><div>{{__($sec_name)}}</div></h5>`

2. Extra div at the end.

Comment: I use vscode editor. When you select one element it highlights its and the closing pair. Traversing through the DOM I could easily spot elements with wrong matching close pair.

Answer (score 0):

your foreach loop is starting after `#accordionExample` but at the end there is 2 closing tag of div.

```
@endforeach;
                </div>
                <!-- End of Lessionss Card -->
            </div>
```

this should be change to

```
                </div>
@endforeach;
                <!-- End of Lessionss Card -->
            </div>
``
```

Comment: not right dear , the loop must be after accordionExample  id ,the pbrolem is solved as i forget delete extra div ,thanks